# Memory Leak In C++ Graph Function (valgrind not specific on line)

Tags: c++, graph, memory-leaks

I'm implementing a Graph using an Edge List in C++. The code executes as intended, but according to valgrind there's a memory leak caused by the AddEdge function. I'm having trouble figuring out what it is since AddEdge and AddVertex are similar, yet AddVertex doesn't leak.

```
  void Graph::AddVertex(string v)
{
  bool full = false;

  try
  {
      VertexNode* location = new VertexNode;
      delete location;
      full = false;
  }
  catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
  {
      full = true;
  }

  if(full == true)
      throw GraphFull();
  else
  {
      VertexNode* temp = new VertexNode;
      temp->vname = v;

      if (vertices == NULL)
      {
          vertices = temp;
          vertices->nextVertex = NULL;
          edges = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
          temp->nextVertex = vertices;
          vertices = temp;
       }
    }

}

    void Graph::AddEdge(string s, string d, int w)
{
     bool full = false;

    try
    {
        EdgeNode* location = new EdgeNode;
        delete location;
        full = false;
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
    { 
        full = true;
    }

  if(full == true)
      throw GraphFull();
  else
  {
      EdgeNode* temp = new EdgeNode;
      temp->weight = w;

      VertexNode* search = vertices;      

      while(search->vname != s)
          search = search->nextVertex;
      temp->source = search;

      search = vertices;

      while(search->vname != d)
          search = search->nextVertex;
      temp->destination = search;      

    if (edges == NULL)
    {
        edges = temp;
        edges->nextEdge = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->nextEdge = edges;
        edges = temp;
    }
    }
}
```

here is the valgrind output:

```
==17435==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==17435==    by 0x401952: Graph::AddEdge(std::string,std::string,int)(in /home/graph)
==17435==    by 0x402255: main (in /home/graph)
```

Comment: Did you compile with -g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither AddEdge nor AddVertex release any of the memory they allocate, so by design the problem is not in these routines at all.  Clearly put, a memory leak is a failure to free the memory before the program closes.  It is only reported that the memory allocated by **the specific routine** remains allocated when the program exited.

The problem is likely not at the time of allocation in `AddEdge`, but rather by the time the program exits, the memory allocated by `AddEdge` was not released (freed).

Did you free the vertices but not the edges?